# Tiled map editor and objects

Tags: sprites, tiles

Ive been searching for an easy way to group multiple sprites of a spritesheet into a single entity. Im using tiled editor as written at the title. Some objects might be larger than the tile size and i need a way to let my game know that in order to manipulate these objects. I dont want to create new tilesets with different sizes for all objects. Is this possible in this app and if not do you know another that can handle this?

Comment: Objects in Tiled are just placeholders. Don't treat them like "actual" objects. You can give them properties if you need to.

Comment: Sorry I was referring to objects in general not "tiled objects". I guess this could work as a workaround but it defeats the purpose of tiled as a -visual- editor...

Comment: Actually I found the solution...turns out it's not possible with the latest official release of Tiled but it IS now possible with one the latest daily builds.

Comment: The visual editing is for the maps themselves. The objects are just a afterthought.

Comment: @user40079 Could you please write the solution as an answer and "accept" it ? So everyone could know the problem has been solved :^)